# How to redirect request for any host to my hostname within a local network

Tags: domain-name-system, web-server, redirect, hostname

I have a local wireless network running. It is not connected to the internet and it has a webserver (lighttpd) running on 192.168.0.1

This webserver has a website running on it.

I want to know how can I redirect the user to "192.168.0.1" whenever he / she tries to access any other IP on this wireless network.

I have "dnsmasq" as my DNS Server.

To summarise:

"http://192.168.0.1"   ==> Allowed to access

"http://193.168.0.1"   ==> Makes no sense in this local wireless network, so want to redirect the user by default to "http://192.168.0.1"

Thanks,
Mahendra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I solved the problem. Posting the solution here back with hope that it helps somebody in the future...

I solved this by modifying the lighttpd.conf file. I added the following inside my lighttpd.conf file:

```
$HTTP["host"] !~ "mydesiredhostname\.com" {
        url.redirect = (
                                "" => "http://192.168.0.1/"
                        )
}
```

I even had to add the following to my dnsmasq.conf file: (thanks to the answer below)

`address=/#/192.168.0.1`

Thank you everybody for your time. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add this row into you dnsmasq.conf:

```
address=/#/192.168.0.1
```

From man page: ... with the additional facility that /#/ matches any domain. Thus --address=/#/1.2.3.4 will always return 1.2.3.4 for any query not answered from /etc/hosts or DHCP...

Comment: Hello @lg, I tried adding this to dnsmasq.conf.. However when I tried to browse "http://www.mydummyhostname.com"  it gave " Server not found " Do you have any idea?

Comment: I suppose you restarted dnsmasq server. Are you sure your client is using dnsmasq as dns server? Try to add address=/mydummyhostname.com/192.168.0.1 in dnsmasq.conf. I edited my response.

Comment: I tried adding "address=/mydummyhostname.com/192.168.0.1" to dnsmasq.conf and it still shows "Server not found" do you have any idea what could be wrong? Am i missing something?

Comment: Check you client DNS configuration. Which S.O. are you using as client?

Answer (score 1):

You can use iptables to redirect 80 port to yours ip

```
iptables -t nat -D PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.1
```

updated

Comment: this command does not work on my linux machine... I am using linux 2.6.32 and its on embedded device.

Comment: try againe. there were some mistakes with - and -- parameters; 
check /sbin/iptables for command